# split a string in java algorithm

Tags: java, string, split

I have the below string :

```
FIELD,KEY,0,AREA,2,3,4
```

I need to pick out the values of `key` and `area` and convert them to integer array .. e.g.

```
key = {0};
area = {2,3,4}
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: you want area as a list of integers?. Will your pattern always be the same?

Comment: what does `FIELD` stand for here?

Comment: Pattern wont be the same. Can add multiple values after the words..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `#indexOf` and `#split` to do this as ***I guess*** your format of `String` is like this

```
FIELD,KEY,key1,key2,ke3...,AREA,area1,area2,area3...
```

---

```
    String input = "FIELD,KEY,0,AREA,2,3,4";
    int indexOfKEY=input.indexOf("KEY");
    int indexOfAREA=input.indexOf("AREA");
    String key[]=input.substring(indexOfKEY+4,indexOfAREA-1).split(",");
    String area[]=input.substring(indexOfAREA+5).split(",");
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
String input = "FIELD,KEY,0,AREA,2,3,4";
String key = input.split(",")[1]; //gets "KEY"
String keyValue = input.split(",")[2]; //gets "0"
```

As a homework, I'm leaving you the task to find the expression that gets `"AREA"`.

Comment: Thank you for doing my 'homework' for me. That would only work in the case the string doesnt get altered. Don't want to use hard coded values. I came up with my own method but its long winded and wanted to see alternatives to do this.

Comment: How about you add that code to your question then? Plus further examples that show the possible alternations that you mentioned.

Comment: Well, seems that I didn't understand what do you exactly need. You can edit your question with more details about your solution and then I can answer again. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that:

```
static Map<String,List<Integer>> parse(String input) {
    Map<String,List<Integer>> result = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>>();
    String[] items = input.split(",");
    int i = 0;
    while (i < items.length) {
        String name = items[i++];
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (i < items.length && items[i].matches("^[0-9]+$")) {
            list.add(Integer.valueOf(items[i++]));
        }
        result.put(name,list);
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,List<Integer>> map = parse("FIELD,KEY,0,AREA,2,3,4");
    System.out.println(map.get("KEY"));
    System.out.println(map.get("AREA"));
}
```